# $(G,*)=(Z_3,+)$ is a group?

Tags: group-theory

$(G,*)=(Z_3,+)$ .$Z_3$ be the set of integers $ mod \ 3$ than the set  will be ${0,1,2}$.
but it doesn't satisfy the property of closure that the sum of two should also be in that group.

Comment: don't forget that the sum of two numbers should be reduced modulo 3 when working in $Z_3$. You do have closure!

Comment: means i have to take take numbers add them and then take the mod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does satisfy the property, since any two objects of $\mathbb Z_3$ also add to an object in $\mathbb Z_3$:

- $0+0=0\in\mathbb Z_3$
- $0+1=1\in\mathbb Z_3$
- $0+2=2\in\mathbb Z_3$
- $1+0=1\in\mathbb Z_3$
- $1+1=2\in\mathbb Z_3$
- $1+2=0\in\mathbb Z_3$
- $2+0=2\in\mathbb Z_3$
- $2+1=0\in\mathbb Z_3$
- $2+2=1\in\mathbb Z_3$